# No matching function for call to 'class'

Tags: c++, class, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to learn and understand multiple inheritance.

I have a 'squat' class that is a child of an 'abandoned' class

Why am I getting the error message no matching function for call to Abandoned::Abandoned()

squatter.cpp|9|error: no matching function for call to 'Abandoned::Abandoned()'|

I have looked at a lot of similar posts on this website relating to this topic. They say they I must declare an object of Abandoned with the right arguments, but I am not trying to use any functions from Abandoned, I only want to link it squat for now.

I think it is something to do with my constructor but I can't work out what the problem is.

Sorry for the big wall of code but I couldn't think of a better way

Here is my squat .cpp/h

```
#ifndef SQUAT_H
#define SQUAT_H
#include<abandoned.h>
#include<building.h>

class Squat:public Buildings, public Abandoned
{
private:
    bool isempty;

public:

    Squat(bool);
    virtual void display();
    virtual void isoccupied(bool);


};



#endif // SQUAT_H
```

and .cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<squat.h>
#include<building.h>
#include<apartment.h>
#include<abandoned.h>


Squat::Squat(bool isitempty):isempty(isitempty){}

void Squat::isoccupied(bool isitempty)
{
    if(isitempty=1)
    {
        isempty=1;
        cout<<"The abandoned building is empty"<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<"The abandoned building is full of dirty squatters"<<endl;
}
```

My understanding is when I have said;

```
class Squat:public Buildings, public Abandoned
```

This has 'linked' the classes together

Below is my abandoned .cpp/h

```
#ifndef ABANDONED_H
#include<vector>
#include<building.h>
#define ABANDONED_H


class Abandoned:public Buildings
{

private:
    int length;
    std::vector<int> status;
    int sum;

public:

    Abandoned(int m_size, int asum);
    Abandoned(bool);
    virtual void getstatus(int);
    virtual void display();
    virtual void demolish(int);
    virtual void rebuild(int);
    //virtual void demolish(int);



};






#endif // ABANDONED_H
```

and my .cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<apartment.h>
#include<building.h>
#include<abandoned.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
using namespace std;

Abandoned::Abandoned(int m_size, int asum): length(m_size), status(m_size, 0), sum(asum)
{}


void Abandoned::getstatus(int m_size)
{
   status.push_back(length);

};

void Abandoned::display()
{
    Buildings::display();
    cout << " length of status is: "<<status.size()<<endl;
}

void Abandoned::demolish(int asum)
{
    if(asum<3)
    {
        cout<<"The building is below the safety standards and should be demolished"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"The building meets the safety standards and can be rebuilt"<<endl;}

}

void Abandoned::rebuild(int asum)
{
    if(asum>3)
    {
        cout<<"The building is above the safety standards and should be rebuilt"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"The building should be demolished"<<endl;}

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of this code is irrelevant to the question at hand. Could you reduce that to an MVCE? TIA.

Comment: In addition to what @Borgleader said, the exact error message as displayed by the compiler would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `Abandoned` does not have a no-arg constructor. That means that any constructor of the derived class must select a constructor to invoke from `Abandoned`:

```
Squat::Squat(bool isitempty): Abandoned(...), isempty(isitempty){}
```

Comment: ahhh I see so I need to put Abandoned(int m_size, int asum) in there?
Could I solve this by also putting a no-arg constructor in abandoned?
thanks for your help

Comment: @TonyHibbert yes you need to provide the size and sum or use the bvool constructor (that you forgot to include) and yes adding a no-arg will fix the compile error as well.

Comment: Thanks, so I put in your suggestions and now the constructor reads 'Squat::Squat(bool isitempty):Abandoned(int m_size, int asum),  isempty(isitempty){}'    and i am getting an error, expected primary expression before int, which is screaming out to me basic error but I cant spot it. Does a no arg constructor just look like Abandoned() {}thanks for your help

Comment: @TonyHibbert `Squat::Squat(bool isitempty, int size, int sum):Abandoned(size, sum), isempty(isitempty){}`

Comment: Thanks ratchet! I had to change the constructor in my squat.h file to Squat(bool, int, int) but that seemed to work..except now I am getting an error 'undefined reference to 'vtable for squat'

Comment: its ok i have fixed it